# Transforming point cloud coordinates

Tags: c++, kinect, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am required to shift the origin to the vertex of a plane obtained after segmentation using pcl. I am aware of the pcl function `getTransformationFromTwoUnitVectorsAndOrigin` which gives the transformation matrix.
But I am not sure how to calculate the unit vector of the planes edges.

I able to get the plane from the point cloud. But not the line equation or unit vector of the edges. I tried to find the planes intersection on the x-z and y-z plane but using that I cannot find the vertex of the plane obtained. That's my major issue. I need the vertex of the plane to fix my origin using the gettransformationFromTwoUnitVectorsAndOrigin.

Any suggestion on how to find the unit vectors along the plane's edges and their intersection point (for placing the origin) will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I'm no expert on kinect or point clouds so I could be off base (and thus not downvoting or voting to close) but this question looks very sparse and open to the stock, "What have you tried so far?" counter question. I recommend expanding the question.

Comment: I able to get the plane from the point cloud. But not the line equation or unit vector of the edges. I tried to find the planes intersection on the x-z and y-z plane but using that I cannot find the vertex of the plane obtained. That's my major issue. I need the vertex of the plane to fix my origin using the gettransformationFromTwoUnitVectorsAndOrigin.

Comment: Good information. Recommend editing the question to add it to the question. You can't count on people perusing the comments for extra relevant bits. Code demonstrating what you've done and tried so far is often helpful because it shows you're serious, not just some punk expecting other people to do their homework, and someone might post a "Try this instead. Way easier." answer or comment.